# Composer - Dataflow hook crash

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm creating a Hourly task in Airflow that schedules a Dataflow Job, however the hook provided by Airflow Library most of the times crashes while the dataflow job actually succeed.

```
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,523] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-05-25 07:05:03,439] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:109} WARNING -   super(GcsIO, cls).__new__(cls, storage_client))
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,721] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: Traceback (most recent call last):
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,725] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 27, in <module>
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,726] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     args.func(args)
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,729] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 392, in run
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,729] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     pool=args.pool,
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,731] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 50, in wrapper
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,732] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     result = func(*args, **kwargs)
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,734] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1492, in _run_raw_task
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,738] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,740] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator.py", line 313, in execute
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,746] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     self.py_file, self.py_options)
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,748] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 188, in start_python_dataflow
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,751] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     label_formatter)
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,753] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 158, in _start_dataflow
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,756] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     _Dataflow(cmd).wait_for_done()
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,757] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 129, in wait_for_done
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,759] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     line = self._line(fd)
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,761] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 110, in _line
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,763] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     line = lines[-1][:-1]
[2018-05-25 07:05:03,766] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: IndexError: list index out of range
```

I look that file up in [Airflow github repo](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py) and the line error does not match which makes me think that the actual Airflow instance from Cloud Composer is outdated. Is there any way to update it?

Answer (score 1):

This would be resolved in 1.10 or 2.0.

Have a look to this PR 
[`https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/3165`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/3165)

This has been merged to master. You may use this PR code and create your own plugin.